# Tortoise git on push says: Error but success

Tags: git, tortoisegit

tortoisegit push ended with "success" but says "error" return code 52.
in fact the push did not happen and the sync still shows the commits as unpushed commits.

[image: Tortoise Git Successfull failure:]

what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is git.exe problem.

Please report to msysgit team.